# Building a bytestring containing the length/size?

Tags: haskell, serialization, bytestring

This isn't the first time I run into this issue, but I haven't found a really nice solution for it so I thought I'd ask how others approach it.

Many protocols include the size of the message (or a part of it) inside the message itself. For instance, right now I'm looking at *ModbusTCP* where bytes 5 and 6 should hold the length of the remaining part of the message. Is there some nice and elegant way to deal with this?

The straight-forward builder would look something like this (using `Serialize` from *cereal*):

```
put (ModTcpRequestFrame tid pid uid req)= do
  putWord16be tid
  putWord16be pid
  putWord16be len
  putWord8 uid
  put req

  where
    len = .... -- what to put here?
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Isn't it just `length uid + length req` (assuming those values are `Foldable`)?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not, in the example above uid is a `Word8` and `req` is a serializable type.

Comment: Just `let reqBS = runPut put req` first and you can calculate the length then later `putByteString reqBS`.  That or find a knot tying solution.

Comment: Well, a knot-tying solution would be pretty much what I'm asking for ;)